# mongodb insert then conditional sum followed by updating sum to another collection

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to

- insert a new record with a points field in to reputationActivity collection
- get sum of points from reputationActivity collection where user id matches
- insert the resulting sum to users collection

Here is mongo playground which does not work right now - https://mongoplayground.net/p/tHgPpODjD6j

```js
await req.db.collection('reputationActivity').insertOne({
  _id: nanoid(),
    "userId": userId,//insert a new record for this user
    "points": points,//insert integer points
},
function(){      
  req.db.collection('reputationActivity').aggregate([ { $match: { userId: userId } }, 
  { TotalSum: { $sum: "$points" } } ]); // sum of point for this user   
      req.db.collection('users').updateOne(
        {_id: userId},
        {$set: {"userTotalPoints": TotalSum}},// set sum in users collection    
        )
    }
  )
});
```

The above code gives me an error that Total sum is not defined. Is it better to do this without a callback function and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> write in one single block of command, use drop command carefully. it's used here to show start to end and illustration purposes only.

```
> db.reputation.drop();
true
> db.reputation.insertOne(
... {_id: 189, "userId": 122, "points": 60});
{ "acknowledged" : true, "insertedId" : 189 }
> var v_userId = 122;
> db.reputation.aggregate([
...     {
...       $match: {
...         userId: v_userId
...       }
...     },
...     {
...       $group: {
...         "_id": null, "TotalSum": {$sum: "$points"}}
...    },
...   ]).forEach(function(doc)
...               {print("TotalSum: " +doc.TotalSum,
...                      "userId: " +v_userId);
...                db.users.updateOne(
...                {"userId":v_userId}, {$set:{"userPoints":doc.TotalSum}});
...               }
...             );
TotalSum: 60 userId: 122
> db.users.find();
{ "_id" : 189, "userId" : 122, "points" : 60, "userPoints" : 60 }
>
```

Comment: When you aggregate with $sum use "group by".
Your error is because there is no group by in the aggregation pipeline.

I tried the sample code with output pasted in code section. Can you please incorporate it in your program to check if the error is removed.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I set up a playground and added group but still not working - https://mongoplayground.net/p/avqdcPREZTh

Comment: Hi Kal, sorry, I have not used mongoplayground before. I am using mongodb installed as local client.  Here is the code end to end executed on client mongodb on windows.

Comment: playground makes it easy to share code and issues. So is TotalSum available outside the aggregate? In my case it does not seem to get that value.

Comment: the aggregate will return the cursor to a set of documents(output). for each iterate on those.

Comment: please use alternates as robo3T or any editor and check your results other than mongoplayground as well. The code I shared is tested.

Comment: I see whats wrong -  There is no need to do foreach. Your code is updating same collection but I am trying to set the total in another collection called users. Please take a look at my question again and the mongoplayground example. My question title also says another collection

Comment: I think I need to use $out to get the value outside the collection to be available to update another collection

Comment: after some discussion with another user who edited your answer, i was able to make it work with a few modifications done based on your answer. thanks !

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to know the issue solved. Thanks for the question and subsequent interactive updates.